# Unable to cast object of type 'WhereEnumerableIterator`1[Object]' to type 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[Object]'

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, linq, webforms

I'm using some free source code to create an e-commerce site in WebForms. It is the Visual Basic version of [Getting Started with ASP.NET 4.5 Web Forms and Visual Studio 2013](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-aspnet-45-web-forms/display_data_items_and_details). I have been successful until I coded the ProductDetails.aspx.vb page. I replaced my object names and properties accordingly, but when I run the project, I get this error:

*Unable to cast object of type 'WhereEnumerableIterator`1[LethalLibrary.Book]' to type 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[LethalLibrary.Book]'.*

**Description:** An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

**Exception Details:** System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'WhereEnumerableIterator`1[LethalLibrary.Book]' to type 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[LethalLibrary.Book]'.

Does Linq from VS2017 differ from VS2013? How do I fix this?

```
Public Function GetBook(<QueryString("BookID")> BookId As Nullable(Of Integer)) As IQueryable(Of Book)
    Dim db = New BookContext()
    Dim query As IQueryable(Of Book) = db.Books
    If BookId.HasValue AndAlso BookId > 0 Then
        query = query.Where(CType(Function(p) p.BookID = BookId, Func(Of Book, Boolean)))
    ElseIf Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(BookTitle) Then
        query = query.Where(Function(p) String.Compare(p.BookTitle, BookTitle) = 0)
    Else
        query = Nothing
    End If
    Return query
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer on ASP.NET's forums. Adding `AsQueryable()` to my `query` variable fixed it!

```
Public Function GetBook(BookId As Nullable(Of Integer)) As IQueryable(Of Book)
    Dim BookTitle As String = "aaaa"
    Dim db = New ApplicationDbContext()
    Dim query As IQueryable(Of Book) = db.Books
    If BookId.HasValue AndAlso BookId > 0 Then
        query = (query.Where(CType(Function(p) p.BookId = BookId, Func(Of Book, Boolean)))).AsQueryable()
    ElseIf Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(BookTitle) Then
        query = (query.Where(Function(p) String.Compare(p.BookTitle, BookTitle) = 0)).AsQueryable()
    Else
        query = Nothing
    End If
    Return query
End Function
```